# Showing page labels of a PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I use `iTextSharp` to display page labels of a PDF file. To do so, I use the following code.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("_file.pdf");
string[] labels = PdfPageLabels.GetPageLabels(reader);
string plabels = null;

for (int l = 0; l < labels.Length; l++)
{
    plabels += labels[l] + "\n";
}
Console.WriteLine(plabels);
```

When page labels in a PDF file look like this:

[image]

the code correctly shows labels:

```
1
ix
A
```

However, when page labels look different (perhaps always when the first page label is a string):

[image]

The code incorrectly shows page labels (notice that second and third label starts with Cover):

```
Cover
Coverix
CoverA
```

Why is this the case? Is it by design?

Comment: I think it's a bug. Which version of iTextSharp are you using? Can the problem be reproduced with the latest version? (The latest 5-series version is 5.5.10; the latest 7-series version is 7.0.1.)

Comment: I did some test. When first label is `Cover` the error is as described in my post. However, when the first label is `C` there is no error. I have found an additional error. Please have a look at this screenshot http://i.imgur.com/fa8eC4q.jpg of page labels in Adobe Acrobat and how they are displayed by iText. I'm using the latest iTextSharp  – 5.5.10.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Will you be inspecting this issue? For the time being I'm removing `Cover` from page labels that start with this string but I'm still interestered in this problem.